# unable to create order in the backend- button/links aren't responding

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, javascript, backend

I am unable to create orders in the backend on Magento. After clicking the 'create new order' button I am directed to my customer list and I'm unable to select a customer. My cursor does change as if it wants to do something when clicked but nothing happens. If I try and click the "Create New Customer" button nothing happens either.

I am not sure if this is related to the issue but I thought it may be worth mentioning. If I go to System>Tools>Backup and try and click "System Backup" "Database and Media Backup"  "Database Backup" nothing happens either. However, these seem to be the only places where the buttons aren't responsive.

I have tried in:
Chrome (Latest Version - 30.0.1599.101)
FireFox ( Latest Version - 24.0 )
Safari (Latest Version - 7.0 )

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.2

Comment: Buttons not responding hint at a javascript error. Open your javascript console and report any errors that may be present.

Comment: @philwinkle I believe this is correct but please let me know if I'm not showing you the correct thing. I logged into the backend of the site where I was experiencing the issue and in firefox went to tools >web developer>console [link]http://i.imgur.com/obaSLGn.png[/link]

Answer (score 1):

I discovered when I disabled 'Merge JavaScript Files' this issue was resolved. I'll have to look into the details and update. If anyone has any tips let me know. Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure you flushed all your merge javascript settings?